# Facebook share displaying weird characters

Tags: facebook, character, share

I just added a facebook share icon to my website, when I hit the button the facebook popup displays weird special characters

the character won't display here but it's a square with 00 over 97

for example instead of a single quote

I tried changing the quote to a the special character `&#8217;` but this doesnt' work either

also tried messing with the charset, but then i'd need to use a special character everytime i need to display a quote.

My site is mostly text-based so I don't want to get involved in that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Put this meta tag in you HTML page, facebook uses UTF-8.

Comment: Another thing to try is add facebook's open graph data, but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem either although I'm no longer getting warnings when I check my urls on facebook.